# How do you interprete a sequence of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I was poking around with metric space $l^1(\mathbb{N})= \{(x_n)_n \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  |x_n| \;   \text{converges} \}$ with the mertric $d_1((x_n)_n, (y_n)_n)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  |x_n -y_n|$ and looking at the sequences of this set. But then I confronted myself for the first time with a sequence of a sequence. Is there any trick or intuition to interpret this?

Comment: One way to think of it which can be helpful (which is little more than a rephrasing of the definition) is as a sequence of a countable, ordered set of real numbers. However, over time you’ll gain intuition for working with these “sequences of sequences” as well.

Comment: You can think about it as 2 dimensional sequence i.e.  2 dimensional matrix with infinite rows and columns. Each row (or column) is point in $l^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I eventually learned to work with it, is as seeing a row as a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ and a row of rows as row of functions $(f_n)_n$. For example, if we have a cauchy sequence $(f_n)_n \in l^{1}(\mathbb{N})=\left\{\left(x_{n}\right)_{n} \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\right| x_{n} \mid\right.$ converges $\}$ than there must be for every $\epsilon >0$ an $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n,m>n_0$ we have that $$d_1(f_n, f_m)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty |f_n(k)-f_m(k)|.$$